# Как правильнее реализовать бэкграунд отправку геоданных?

Tags: java, android

Нужно отправлять раз в 30 сек геоданные во время работы приложения. Что для этого лучше использовать? Просто отдельный тред сойдет или есть шанс что android его прибьет? service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точного ответа нет, так как это очень зависит от версии Android на которой вы запускаете. Если до версии 6 можно было использовать Service, то начиная с 23 SDK его работа не гарантируется (Doze mode), надо использовать Foreground Service, а в версии O+ скорее всего и эта возможность будет ограничена.

- Вот тут есть пример для ForegroundService:
  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService
- Тут описана политика Google относительно обновлений локации:
  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits
- Как жить на версии O посмотрите в этой лабе:
  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html#0